# Complex parsing a text file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, parsing, text

So I am trying to parse a TXT file which has the following format. Each entry is on a single line.

SAMPLE.TXT

```
2016-02-24 13:54:23 Local0.Info 172.16.120.4    1 1456311263.500015263 ASD_MX600 urls src=172.16.41.15:62490 dst=144.76.76.148:80 mac=00:1B:0D:63:84:00 user=CN=Smith\John,OU=S-HS,OU=SAcc,DC=abc,DC=org,DC=ab agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 seb/2.0 SEBKEY' request: GET http://something.com/theme/image.php/clean/page/1455532301/icon

2016-02-24 13:54:23 Local0.Info 172.16.120.4    1 1456311263.500097075 ASD_MX600 urls src=172.16.41.15:62485 dst=144.76.76.148:80 mac=00:1B:0D:63:84:00 user=CN=Smith\John,OU=S-HS,OU=SAcc,DC=abc,DC=org,DC=ab agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 seb/2.0 SEBKEY' request: GET http://somethingelse.com/theme/image.php/clean/core/1455532301/f/pdf-24
```

I need to do the following:

1. Parse the entire file into an array. //DONE

2. Pick up everything after 1  145... (which will end up in [3] of the array) and parse it further so that I have the following breakdowns.
 - urls
 - src=172.16.41.15:62490
 - dst=144.76.76.148:80
 - mac=00:1B:0D:63:84:00
 - user=CN=Smith\John,OU=S-HS,OU=SAcc,DC=abc,DC=org,DC=ab
 - agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 seb/2.0 SEBKEY'
 - request: GET
 - http://something.com/theme/image.php/clean/page/1455532301/icon

I am having a hard time getting the syntax right for the 2nd parse within the main loop. I get the entire giant section from index 3 [3] and I think I am also using the explode() right to chop it off based on ' ' but then I am lost. How do i get hold of the data as shown above? My code progress so far:

```
<?php

$txt_file    = file_get_contents('C:\sample.txt');
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
array_shift($rows);

foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode('   ', $data);   //chop each row first based on bigger space

  //--------------------------
    $info[$row]['timestamp']           = $row_data[0];
   // $info[$row]['localinfo']         = $row_data[1];
    $info[$row]['ip']  = $row_data[2];
    $info[$row]['other']       = $row_data[3]; //This is where LONGEST string exists
  //--------------------------

    $row_data1 = explode(' ', $row_data[3]);   //chop index item based on smaller space

    $rowd_data2[$row_data1]['urlsflows']           = $row_data1[3];


     //display data
  //  echo 'Row ' . $row . ' TIMESTAMP: ' . $info[$row]['timestamp'] . '<br />';
   // echo 'Row ' . $row . ' LOCALINFO: ' . $info[$row]['localinfo'] . '<br />';
   // echo 'Row ' . $row . ' IP: ' . $info[$row]['ip'] . '<br />';

  //--The line below is where I am lost. Kindly help.

    echo $rowd_data2[$row_data1]['urlsflows'];


      } //end of for loop

?>
```

Comment: Could you add your current result?

Comment: Hi - Currently nothing gets displayed. I think the 2nd explode needs another loop to go through? Thanks.

Comment: From your sample data above your `$row_data` array would have two elements in it, as there is only one bigger whitespace. So `$row_data1 = explode(' ', $row_data[3]);` should actually be `$row_data1 = explode(' ', $row_data[1]);`

Comment: Hi Sam - Actually the sample data did not paste properly. There are big SPACES after 1st, 2nd and 3rd column of data. Regular spaces after that. Thanks.

Comment: @SKro, you can use `file` of PHP

Answer (score 1):

This code works for the input file:

```
<?php
$rows = explode("\n", file_get_contents('SAMPLE.TXT'));
$result = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (trim($row) == "") {
        continue;
    }
    $timeMatches = array();
    $reTime = "/([0-9-]* [0-9:]*) /";
    preg_match($reTime, $row, $timeMatches);
    $re = "/src=(.*) dst=(.*) mac=(.*) user=(.*) agent=(.*) request: (.*) (.*)/";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($re, $row, $matches);
    $result[] = array('time' => $timeMatches[1], 'src' => $matches[1]
                , 'dst' => $matches[2], 'mac' => $matches[3]
                , 'user' => $matches[4], 'agent' => $matches[5]
                , 'method' => $matches[6], 'url' => $matches[7]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

The output of the var_dump($result) is:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["time"]=>
    string(20) "2016-02-24 13:54:23"
    ["src"]=>
    string(18) "172.16.41.15:62490"
    ["dst"]=>
    string(16) "144.76.76.148:80"
    ["mac"]=>
    string(17) "00:1B:0D:63:84:00"
    ["user"]=>
    string(49) "CN=Smith\John,OU=S-HS,OU=SAcc,DC=abc,DC=org,DC=ab"
    ["agent"]=>
    string(76) "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 seb/2.0 SEBKEY'"
    ["method"]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["url"]=>
    string(63) "http://something.com/theme/image.php/clean/page/1455532301/icon"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["time"]=>
    string(20) "2016-02-24 13:54:23"
    ["src"]=>
    string(18) "172.16.41.15:62485"
    ["dst"]=>
    string(16) "144.76.76.148:80"
    ["mac"]=>
    string(17) "00:1B:0D:63:84:00"
    ["user"]=>
    string(49) "CN=Smith\John,OU=S-HS,OU=SAcc,DC=abc,DC=org,DC=ab"
    ["agent"]=>
    string(76) "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 seb/2.0 SEBKEY'"
    ["method"]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["url"]=>
    string(71) "http://somethingelse.com/theme/image.php/clean/core/1455532301/f/pdf-24"
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising Kordi! Shall play with it. Thank you.

Comment: One question Kordi - How do I access individual elements in the $result[ ]? As in - how is the data stored inside it? Thanks.

Comment: Dumped the output, so its clear. If you want to access the method of the first line just use $result[0]['method']

Comment: Hi kordi - Never mind. I think I got it.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Kordi! But the format seems wrong. Is there a toTime( ) function which can change it back to the format it was in the file? Thanks again!

Comment: Format was 1456311263.500015263 in the File its seconds since 1970. Or which time do you need?! Just dont get it!

Comment: Sorry Kordi. I am new to PHP. :) I just need the value as it is in the file -> 2016-02-24 13:54:23  ... thats all. Is there a way to do this with the 1456311263.500015263 format?

Comment: Change it. The other Dateformat is the seconds since 1970. Its the so called Unix Time. See here for additional information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Hi Kordi - Does your code also work for rows that DO NOT match? I have rows in the TXT file where there is no "user= " and maybe thats why it is not working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('C:\sample.txt');
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
array_shift($rows);

$info = [];
foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode('   ', $data);   //chop each row first based on bigger space

  //--------------------------
    $info[$row] = [];
    list($info[$row]['timestamp'], $info[$row]['ip'],$info[$row]['other'] ) = explode(" ", $row_data[0]);

   // $info[$row]['localinfo']         = $row_data[1];

  //--------------------------

    $row_data1 = explode(' ', $row_data[1]);   //chop index item based on smaller space

    $rowd_data2[$row_data1]['urlsflows']           = $row_data1[3];


     //display data
  //  echo 'Row ' . $row . ' TIMESTAMP: ' . $info[$row]['timestamp'] . '<br />';
   // echo 'Row ' . $row . ' LOCALINFO: ' . $info[$row]['localinfo'] . '<br />';
   // echo 'Row ' . $row . ' IP: ' . $info[$row]['ip'] . '<br />';

  //--The line below is where I am lost. Kindly help.

    echo $rowd_data2[$row_data1]['urlsflows'];


      } //end of for loop

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("C:\sample.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo $line = fgets($myfile) . "<br>";// you can do the explode and assignment here.
    //example
    $row_data = explode(' ', $line);
    //don't worry about spaces, it will trim by PHP `trim` function, that will erase all the spaces
}
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Frayne - This looks interesting and simple. How do i extract single line elements like I need from this $row_data[] ? Kindly assist. Thanks.

Comment: I thought, you need to `explode` by only `space`. if you have big `whitespace` then start with it. Either your important lost.

Comment: @SKro, But in this way you can also do the things and no need of extra explode like you do for getting the `$rows`

Comment: Hi Frayne - I need some more help. Can you please give an example of how I can extract single elements from the row_data variable? Do I need to use "explode" again? Or just use index number  [ ] ? Thanks.

Comment: @SKro, Yes every time you have to explode for splitting the string.

Comment: @SKro, You need to explode with largest white space and then explode the smaller one. every time you will get an array as return value. then again you have to use explode for further split.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Frayne.

Comment: Just explode it another time if the ltrim not working.

Comment: If it works for you then why not you upvote my answer or accept?