# Parse disjointed TXT file in PHP based on string matches?

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

So I have a TXT file that is disjointed. How do I parse it so that it can use string matches to figure out data?

From the sample below I want:

```
timestamp = 
src=
dst=
user=
agent=
request:
url=
```

The value should be NULL if it was not found on the line. I tried using `preg_match()` but it does not execute the entire file. No outputs.

Thank you.

Sample.txt

> 2016-02-24 13:54:23   Local0.Info 172.16.120.4    1 1456311263.806656820
>   ASD_MX600 flows src=108.177.15.189 dst=213.130.115.218 protocol=udp
>   sport=443 dport=61907 pattern: 1 all
>
> 2016-02-24 13:54:23 Local0.Info 172.16.120.4    1 1456311263.500015263
>   ASD_MX600 urls src=172.16.41.15:62490 dst=144.76.76.148:80
>   mac=00:1B:0D:63:84:00
>   user=CN=Smith\John,OU=S-HS,OU=SAcc,DC=abc,DC=org,DC=ab
>   agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101
>   seb/2.0 SEBKEY' request: GET
>   http://something.com/theme/image.php/clean/page/1455532301/icon
>
> 2016-02-24 14:29:14   Local0.Info 172.16.120.4    1 1456313354.489880924
>   ASD_MX600 urls src=172.16.41.143:57256 dst=74.125.232.155:443
>   mac=00:1C:B0:10:A8:00 request: UNKNOWN
>   https://4780928.fls.doubleclick.net/...

Also, I had asked a similar question here -> [Complex parsing a text file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622477/complex-parsing-a-text-file-in-php) - but there was no room to ask an additional extension to the same so posting a new question. Thank you.

SK

PS: Code I have tried but does not work.

EXAMPLE 1

```
$myfile = fopen("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\LogCatcher Script\SyslogCatchAll-2016-02-25.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file


while(!feof($myfile)) {

   $line = fgets($myfile) . "<br>";// you can do the explode and assignment here.
    //example
    $row_data = explode("   ", $line);     //FIRST BLAST

   $timestamp = $row_data[0] ;         //Pick up the timestamp for Column 1
   $timestamp;

   //SECOND BLAST
   $remainingData = explode(" ",$row_data[3]);     //chop it off
   $src =   $remainingData[4];
   $src = ltrim($src, "src=");

    $dst=   $remainingData[5];
    $dst = ltrim($dst, "dst=");

    $usr = $remainingData[7];
    if (preg_match('/user=/',$usr))
      {
    $usr = ltrim($usr, "user=");
      }
      else  {
      $usr = "No User Found";
      }
```

... This is where it starts to spasm out since not every line has"user="...

EXAMPLE 2
Another way I tried using another user's code.

```
<?php
$rows = explode("\n", file_get_contents('sample.txt'));
$result = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (trim($row) == "") {
        continue;
    }
    $timeMatches = array();
    $reTime = "/([0-9-]* [0-9:]*) /";
    preg_match($reTime, $row, $timeMatches);
    $re = "/src=(.*) dst=(.*) mac=(.*) user=(.*) agent=(.*) request: (.*) (.*)/";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($re, $row, $matches);
    $result[] = array('time' => $timeMatches[1], 'src' => $matches[1]
                , 'dst' => $matches[2], 'mac' => $matches[3]
                , 'user' => $matches[4], 'agent' => $matches[5]
                , 'method' => $matches[6], 'url' => $matches[7]);
}

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Runs and displays nothing. Just ends.

Comment: You've forgotten the code that doesn't work in your question.

Comment: Hi Toto - Have added the 2 ways I have tried to solve this without much success. Thanks.